# Gradle Incompatible Return Types

Tags: gradle

When I run the `gradle tasks` command using the following gradle.build file:

```
import org.gradle.api.reporting.Report
import org.gradle.api.reporting.ReportContainer

import org.gradle.api.reporting.internal.TaskReportContainer

interface MyReportContainer extends ReportContainer<Report> {}

class MyDefaultReportContainer extends TaskReportContainer<Report> implements MyReportContainer {}
```

I receive the following fatal exception during script compilation:

> The return type of org.gradle.api.NamedDomainObjectCollection
>   matching(groovy.lang.Closure) in
>   org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection is
>   incompatible with org.gradle.api.NamedDomainObjectSet in
>   org.gradle.api.NamedDomainObjectSet

This seems odd to me, as `NamedDomainObjectSet` directly extends `NamedDomainObjectCollection` ...so how could it be incompatible?

I came across this while trying to write a custom reporting task, following along the example of `DefaultDependencyReportContainer` in the Gradle source which seems to follow exactly this pattern!

Oddly enough, if I switch to:

```
interface MyReportContainer extends org.gradle.api.DomainObjectCollection<Report> {}
```

everything works just fine!

I'm using:

- Gradle 2.2.1
- Build time:   2014-11-24 09:45:35 UTC
- Build number: none
- Revision:     6fcb59c06f43a4e6b1bcb401f7686a8601a1fb4a
- JVM:          1.8.0 (Oracle Corporation 25.0-b70)
- Groovy:       2.3.6

So can anyone tell me why this is failing?

Comment: I am running into the exact same error when trying to use and instance of `NamedDomainObjectContainer` as a `@Delegate`: `class ConfigurationEntryPoint { @Delegate protected final NamedDomainObjectContainer configs`